# React Material-UI Line break working in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: reactjs, safari, material-ui, textfield, multiline

I have tried both `&#10;` and `\n` but the line break placeholder is not working in Safari but in Chrome its working fine.
I have also tried this https://codesandbox.io/s/z354lwp3r4 this but no luck

> ```
> <TextField
>        className="in_multiline"
>        multiline
>        placeholder={"First Line. \n\nSecond Line"}
>        rows={5}
>        value={state.special_instructions}
>        onChange={(e) => { }}
>        variant="outlined"
>   />
> ```

Expected Result for a placeholder on safari

```
First Line.
Second Line
```